# Where is RequestMapping?

Tags: java, spring

I downloaded spring-framework-2.5.6.SEC01-with-dependencies.zip.

There is the RequestMapping javadoc in spring-framework-2.5.6.SEC01\docs\api\org\springframework\web\bind\annotation\

But in the spring-framework-2.5.6.SEC01\dist\spring.jar I can't find the RequestMapping class and the package org.springframework.web.bind.

Am I downloading the correct file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it in spring-framework-2.5.6.SEC01\dist\modules\spring-webmvc.jar